# n-Cube as a Cayley Graph

Tags: graphs, terminology, group-theory

I'm taking a class on graph theory that uses "Graph Theory (Graduate Texts in Mathematics)" by Bondy and Murty. One of the questions is about Cayley graphs and the n-cube, and I don't understand how to interpret it. It runs as follows:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a group and $S$ be a subset of $\Gamma$ not including the
>   identity element. Suppose that the inverse of every element in $S$ also
>   belongs to $S$. The Cayley graph of $\Gamma$ with respect to $S$ is the graph
>   $CG(\Gamma, S)$ with vertex set $\Gamma$ in which two vertices $x$ and $y$ are
>   adjacent iff $xy^{-1}\in S$.

Okay. I follow so far.

> Recall that the n-cube is the graph whose vertex set is the set of all
>   n-tuples of 0s and 1s, where two n-tuples are adjacent if they differ
>   in precisely one coordinate.

Makes sense.

> Show that the n-cube is a Cayley graph.

What does it mean to talk about "$xy$" when $x$ and $y$ are n-tuples? What is the inverse of an n-tuple?

Someone I asked about the problem suggested that I treat $\Gamma$ here as the additive group $({\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z})^n$, and so take $xy^{-1}$ to mean elementwise subtraction of $y$ from $x$, mod 2. But then it seems like $(0, 0, ..., 0)\in\Gamma$ and, since it's the identity element, every vertex will have an edge connecting to it, and that isn't what the n-cube looks like. Googling, I also see that there is an [interpretation of tuples as nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Tuples_as_nested_sets), but then I don't see how the product of two nested sets would ever be in S, since it will have a different cardinality from either of the original tuples. Interpreting the tuples as vectors can't work either since then $xy^{-1}$ will have different dimensions than either of the original tuples.

What is this question asking?

Comment: If every vertex has an edge connecting to (0,0,...,0), then every non-identity element is in S. $\hspace{1.01 in}$

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is asking you to find a suitable group $\Gamma$ and a subset $S$, so that $CG(\Gamma,S)$ is the n-cube.

Since by definition of $CG$, the nodes are the elements of $\Gamma$, you don't have a choice here, leaving the group operation and $S$.

$xy$ and the inverse of $y$ are then understood with respect to the group operation you choose.

Also be aware that the identity element being in $\Gamma$ does not imply that all other vertices are connected with it, since the edges are determined by $S$, not $\Gamma$.

Comment: Okay, so any $\Gamma$ will work? In particular, I could, say, call $\Gamma$ the set of all n-bit integers, define the group operation to be XOR, and let $S$ be all of the powers of two, from 0 to $n$? And provide a mapping from n-element tuples to n-bit integers to show that they're equivalent?

Comment: @PatrickCollins That should work.